# working with HUGE spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

i have about 300,000 records in this spreadsheet. and there are a couple hundred columns!!

one of the columns is the social security number and i need to replace it with some random identifier. i cant really do a vlookup because that is too taxing so i think i am going to write a macro

can anyone please suggest to me how do i do this?

please note that the social security numbers appear multiplle times. so i need them to map correctly to the new unique identifier

Comment: At least consider putting this in in a database!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a hash based on the current SSN.

An example is [here](http://splinter.com.au/blog/?p=86) using SHA1 hash. Plenty of other options exist, including creating your own.

Comment: this is a brilliant idea actually!!! so far it is working, 74% we'll see what happens!

Comment: I'd like to point out that ChristopheD's advice is sound. While the hashing of sensitive data would possibly apply there as well, you may want to consider putting this in a database. It might simply things, especially as it grows even bigger!

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply enter a Random number in the column in question, like =RAND(), double-click the bottom corner of the cell to copy the formula to the bottom of your sheet, then copy/paste special value the column on itself to get rid of the formula?

Comment: This wouldn't handle the case of the duplicate SS#.

Comment: Would this handle mapping identical social security numbers to the same random identifier (as in the question)?

Comment: The unique identifier constraint was added after my initial reply, have to think about whether this can be done easily!